# Connection error with node js while connecting to postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to postgresql database using nodejs. I'm able to connect to only postgre instance in localhost or public ip. But i'm unable to connect to postgre instance in other machine of either the same or different network.What could be the reason.I even tried changing the pg_hba.conf file to listen to all ips even though the same error occurs

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ip:port
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14).

What should i do to overcome this error? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: How did you get your public IP?

Comment: I'm using aws server.Im able to connect to postgres instance in aws server.And I'm also able to connect to other postgres instances in same LAN.But I'm not able to connect to postgres instance in other LAN.How can i achieve this.Is it possible.